# Что в себе хранят примитивные типы до инициализации в Java?

Tags: java, типы

Что в себе хранят примитивные типы до инициализации в Java?

Comment: Вы про значения по умолчанию хотите спросить? Если да, то это `0` и `false`

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если это локальные переменные (*local variables*) - ничего. Вы получите ошибку компиляции при обращении к переменной что не была инициализирована.

Eсли поля класса/обьекта (*class/instance fields*) - значения по умолчанию:

- ссылочние типы - `null`;
- примитивные типы - `0` (`false` для `boolean`).

Answer (score 3):

При загрузке классов в память происходит ряд действий в строго определённом порядке. Когда доходит дело до инициализации полей класса, то они принимают значения по умолчанию (`false` для `boolean` типа и `0` для всех остальных примитивов и `null` для всех непримитивов) или явно присвоенное им значение.

Answer (score 1):

Примитивные типы и их значения по умолчанию:

```
short = 0 
byte = 0 
int = 0
double = .0d
float = .0f
long = 0L
char = \u0000
boolean = false
```

Ссылка на документацию:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: для `char` это `'\u0000'`, `D` (`d`) для `double` не обязательная (как и для `long`)

Comment: String - не примитивный тип

Comment: @LEQADA, поправил, технически не является примитивным, а так табличка есть тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html